# How to do multiplication of value in an array for Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have 2 tables in Google Sheet: Order and ItemOrder.

Order Table: 
[image: Order Table]

ItemOrder Table:
[image]

The idea is that if I ticked all ORD0002 in ItemOrder Table, the Packed column in Order Table should be ticked as well.
I have successfully getting the array of the packed using the Filter function. The question now, can I multiple the value within the array. Understand that unticked is 0/FALSE and ticked is 1/TRUE. If I multiple everything and it is 0, then the value in Order Table should also be 0. It will be 1 only if all the values in ItemOrder are 1.

Or is there any other way to achieve this without script?

Comment: Just reference it. `=RANGE` It will take the value for eg: `=A1` or maybe `=Sheet1!D3`

Comment: @Madhurjya That would work for a single cell.

Comment: Maybe you can use `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Formula:

```
=AND(FILTER(A1:B14, A1:A14 = D3))
```

Apply this formula to `Order Table`. In my case, I put that on `E3`

Sample Sheet where it is used:

[image: multiple-check]

Another screenshot for clarity:

[image: checked]

Unchecking:

[image: uncheck]

Using ARRAYFORMULA

`=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(FILTER(B1:B14,A1:A14=D3)))`

[image: using arrayformula]

NB: Here `example 1` is of the previous formula. `example 2` is using `ARRAYFORMULA`

Comment: This really solves my problem. However how to put this in arrayformula, I am trying to create =ARRAYFORMULA(AND(FILTER($A$1:$A,$B$1:$B=D3:D))) but it keeps giving me error.

Comment: @BrianChew Added. Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: It says AND has no valid input data. May I ask, in term of efficiency, which is better do arrayformula, or create single formula and copy the formula down?